# how to make line item "Ready to Delivery State" in DFP publisher admistration account

Tags: google-dfp

I am working dfp ads,ads are coming when we are using unit test id,
But i want create my own Unit ad Id,So I have created the account of dfp for small business [dfp account](http://ww.google.co.in/doubleclick/publishers/small-business/)

and i have Created the Order ,
delivery start date and end date
but Order in line item is Ready state,

I am not able to find the place ,To change Order ready state to Delivering state .

I will great help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So, your line item is ready to deliver impressions. Only thing left out is to get the tags up and ready on the page. Ensure that the page where it's supposed to be delivered has the ad tag with all the custom criteria and meets the targeting condition (ad unit, country, device etc)